# Multiple currency  displayed in ubercart product page

Tags: 6, ubercart

I have a website where I need to display the product in 2 different currencies. Once the user selects one price, adds the product to cart, and tries to checkout, the currency can be posted to the payment gateway in USD. For example, if the user selects the price in Indian Rupees as 450 INR and tries to checkout, the value is converted into USD if the user pays through Paypal, but if the user selects the Indian Payment gateway, the same will be posted as 450 INR. How can we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Ubercart Currency Conversion](http://drupal.org/project/uc_currency_convert). From the project page:

> This module converts prices of ubercart products from one currency to
>   another currency. The target currency will be selected as follows
>
> 1. Administrators can select the currency and force all prices to be
>      automatically converted
> 2. If the above is not set, then the currency is determined based on
>      user's address
> 3. If the above is not possible, then the site's default currency is
>      used.
>
> The module depends on Currency module.